# How to create custom 404page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create custom 404 page for my site.I mean when i type url as

```
http://example.com/anydummytext
```

need to redirect to custom 404page

How to create custom page for this

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is create a controller you can name the error controller to any what you want.

Example

```
<?php

class Not_found extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
       // some content

       $this->load->view('not_found');
   }

}
```

Then on another controller you can redirect it

```
redirect('not_found');
```

#### Example Only

```
<?php

 class Home extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {

       $result = $this->some_model->get();

       if ($result) {
          // content

          $this->load->view('home');

       } else {
          redirect('not_found');
       }

   }
 }
```

The other option is in config/routes.php you can use codeigniter

```
$route['404_override'] = 'not_found'; // Note will not work in a subfolder
```

Comment: Agreed on this.  One possible adjustment: you maybe don't need a standalone controller for this.  It could just be a function within an existing controller that could that have a custom route setup.

Comment: @user4419336  in model what we need to write code..i mean what is some_model

Comment: That was just to give you example only.

Comment: ya..but what to call in model , i dont hav any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new controller or use existing controller to write down a function for loading the **VIEW** for **404**.

```
class Nopage extends CI_Controller
{
    /* Index function
     *
     * return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('nopage_404');
        }
    }
}
```

Call the controller function in **config->routes** as below.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'nopage';
```

Comment: What is the issue?